# django: second for loop produces no elements

Tags: django, for-loop, recordset

I'm fetching a recordset, and doing a for loop to display the data like so:

```
{% for category in categories %}
    {"img":"{{ category.pr_image }}",
     "url":"{{ category.pr_store_url }}",
     "type":"ca",
     "price":"{{ category.pr_price }}",
     "store":"{{ category.pr_store }}",
     "name":"{{ category.pr_name }}",
     "lat":"{{ category.st_lat }}",
     "long":"{{ category.st_long }}"},
{% endfor %}
```

That works great.

However, a few lines of code down the line i have this, which does not work so great:

```
{% for category in categories %}
<li class="msli">
  <ul class="detali">
<li><a href="{{ category.pr_store_url }}" target="_blank">{{ category.pr_store }}</a></li>
<li>Category: {{ category.pr_cat_name }}</li>
  </ul>
</li>
{% endfor %}
```

As far as i can tell it's the same code, only different formating. If code 1 produces one result, Code 2 does produce one output, but no data. The output is only:

```
<li class="msli">
    <ul class="detali">
    <li><a target="_blank" href=""/></li>
    <li>Category: </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

And no data...
What am i doing wrong?

Oh, and both for cycles are wrapped in a if case...

```
{% if products or stores or categories %}
```

Comment: Please post the view code that create the categories value.

Comment: If you delete the whole first loop, then does the second loop work?

Comment: There's nothing in the original question that points to the reason. Either there's an issue in the view code (see other commenters), or the use of "if products OR stores OR categories" (emphasis on 'OR' is my doing) is causing a section of the categories template to be rendered where there are no 'categories'. The issue here could be anything: either the view code, the "few lines of code down" in the template, or the categories model.

Comment: It seems as if the first loop almost exhausts an iterator but leaves one more in the pipeline. A sentinel? It'd be interesting to know more about the mystery object rendered in the second for loop. You can try to tease out its identity with {{ category|pprint }}. But the most useful thing would be, as others have said, to post information about the view and the categories -object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad, it was another category that was triggering the output, all is well with the code above.